# What is the most simplified form of $y(x′z + xz′) + x(yz + yz′)$

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am stuck on a problem that I know the logical answer to, yet I cannot seem to simplify properly to get there.

- I want to simplify $$F(x,y,z)=y(x′z + xz′) + x(yz + yz′)$$
- I know the simplest form (using a truth table) is $$xy + yz$$
- Yet my simplification yields $$xy + x’yz$$

My steps are below with the identities used

$y(x′z + xz′) + x(yz + yz′)$
$y(x′z + xz′) + x(y(z + z’))$ Distributive
$y(x′z + xz′) + x(y(1))$    Inverse
$y(x′z + xz′) + xy$    Identity
$yx’z + yxz’ + xy$    Distributive
$y(x’z + xz’ + x)$    Distributive
$y(x’z + x)$    Absoption
$yx’z + yx$    Distributive
$\mathbf {xy + x’yz}$    Commutative x 2

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your simplification:

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
xy+x'yz&=&xy(z+z')+x'yz\\
&=& xyz+xyz'+x'yz\\
&=& xyz+xyz+xyz'+x'yz\\
&=& (xyz+xyz')+(xyz+x'yz)\\
&=& xy+yz
\end{array}$$

Comment: This is helpful since it follows the simplification direction that I was heading!

Comment: Good.  I'm glad it was helpful!

Comment: It seems that whenever there doesn't seem to be a next step, ANDing an inverse (1) will yield more variables to work with. This is a good strategy.

Comment: Yeah, when it works.  To be honest, knowing (from your post) what we were shooting for helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just write
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
y(x′z+xz′)+x(yz+yz′) &=& y(x'z+xz')+xyz+xyz' \\
&=&y(x'z+xz')+yxz+yxz' \\
&=&y(x'z+xz'+xz+xz') \\
&=&y(x'z+xz+xz') \\
&=&y(x'z+xz+xz+xz') \\
&=&y((x'+x)z+x(z+z')) \\
&=&y(z+x).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: This is an upworthy answer because it showed me that I did not approach the problem in the simplest terms from the start. Distributing the second OR part to find that there is a common y in all parts is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

$x+z$ is equivalent to $x+x'z$. I don't remember the law. Absorption may be? The proof can be obtained from the true/false table or as follows:
$$
(x+x'z)'=x' (x+z')=x'z'=(x+z)'
$$

Comment: Could you be referring to the [consensus theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem)?

Comment: I believe so. But I don't remember.